# ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter cannot find symbol

Tags: java, netbeans, netty

I try to make simple chat program base on this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsz-assb1X8.).

```
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;

public class ChatClientHandler extends ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter<String>
{

}
```

I get `cannot find symbol` error. I'd also tried change `SimpleInboundHandlerAdapter` to `SimpleInboundHandlerAdapter` but with same result.

Comment: What version of netty are you using? I think interfaces were changed a bit...

Comment: 4.0.17. I also checked 3.9.0

Comment: Take a look at SimpleChannelInboundHandler http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/SimpleChannelInboundHandler.html

Answer (score 2):

The class **ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter** are not able in the last releases.
If you want to use **ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter** anyway you have to update the netty version to 4.0.0.CR3
In maven you have to add the following dependency in order to work with this class

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all -->
   <dependency>
     <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
     <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.0.CR3</version>
</dependency>
```

or even better you can upgrade to the last stable version. At this moment is 4.1.5.Final ...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and extends of SimpleChannelInboundHandler instead of ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter as showed below:

```
public class ChatClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Te fuiste para lo de Visconti: " + msg);
}
```

}

keep in mind that channelRead0 method name will be renamed to messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, I) in 5.0 version